# Updated files are not updating the website hosted in Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean

I have a React-NodeJS('Express' framework) website that is hosted in the Digital Ocean. I have used 'pm2' as the process manager and 'nginx' as the reverse proxy for the website. Recently, I have made some changes to the 'src' folder files of React, pushed it to the Github repo, and finally pulled them to the server. The respective changes in the files are showing in the server as expected. But the website is not displaying the changes that should have after the file changes are made. It is displaying the old version of the website without the changes. What do I need to do to bring the changes in the website as per the updated files on the server?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing server caching? And try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I did not set up server caching manually. But if it is automatically done by the server, then I am not aware about it. As for the browser cache, I have cleared them; but it did not have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of changes are you expecting?
You may want to try:

- Restarting the server that you run using pm2: `pm2 restart app_name`.
- Refresh and force your browser to ignore cache: `ctrl+shift+r` in chrome.

Comment: I have tried the methods that you have suggested. But unfortunately, it did not work. Here is the kind of changes that I am expecting--     Suppose, originally I had the word "Services" in one of my pages. I have updated the word to "Our Services" in the corresponding file in the server. Now, the file is properly updated; but the website is still showing "Services" instead of "Our Services".

Comment: Have you checked the code on the server? Make sure they are up to date with the one in your version control. Also, if you have some configuration to build your code before running them, make sure to have done that too.

Comment: Rebuilding the "build" folder and restarting "nginx" did the trick for me. Not so sure if it is the correct method, but it did work.

Comment: It must be rebuilding the build folder, restarting nginx is only useful if you recently made changes to the nginx configuration (like adding a new server/proxy). Depending on your configuration, if you are running from build folder, rebuilding it everytime there is changes is a must.